# Wildcard Route for Active Class in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, html-helper

I have an IsActive method that I can call to set the active class based on the routes action / controller.

```
public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string action, string controller)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
        var routeController = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

        var isActive = string.Equals(controller, routeController, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                       && string.Equals(action, routeAction, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        return isActive ? "active" : null;
    }
}
```

I have a tri level navigation that needs the active class applied in two spots.  On the actual link and on the menu where the link is nested.

```
<li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-building fa-fw"></i> <span>&nbsp;Company</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="@Html.IsActive("MAYBEAWILDCARDHERE", "CompanyInformation")">
                <a href="#"> Information <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="@Html.IsActive("Index", "CompanyInformation")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "CompanyInformation")"> Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Calendar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Setup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

The Company, Information should return active when the controller `CompanyInformation` is accessed. Is there a way to use some sort of a wildcard that says maybe when any action is accessed under this controller apply the active class?

Comment: Then exclude your action parameter from the helper method or create another extension that work only on controller. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Your code is right, but Siva is also right.

Comment: Thanks Siva. That works perfect.